# SIGABRT message only with iOS5

Tags: ios, uiview, crash, core-animation, ios5

I'm facing a strange crash of my app that occurs only with iOS5. The problem seems to be with my core animation method bellow, because when I set no value for aAnimation.repeatCount or 0 it is working, but when it rotates I use get SIGABRT message with error: -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9628100 when I touch device/simulator screen.

any help will be appreciated

My view definition

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    UIView  *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    self.view = contentView;
    [contentView release];
}
```

setting a subView

```
- (void)setUpPlacardView:(NSInteger)picture {
    // Create the placard view -- its init method calculates its frame based on its image
    PlacardView *aPlacardView = [[PlacardView alloc] init:picture asColor:asColor];
    aPlacardView.desaturation = kotucHue;
    self.placardView = aPlacardView;
    [aPlacardView release];
    [self.view addSubview:placardView];
}
```

SubView definition

```
@interface PlacardView : UIView {


    UIImage                 *placardImage;
    float                   saturation;
    UIColor                 *barva;
    BOOL                    switchMode;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *placardImage;
@property (nonatomic)       float     desaturation;
@property (readwrite) BOOL              switchMode;


// Initializer for this object
- (id)init:(NSInteger)picture asColor:(BOOL)farba;


@end
```

and make rotation

```
- (void)makeKspinning
{
    // Create a transform to rotate in the z-axis
    float radians = 3.120;   
    CATransform3D transform;
    if (rotation) {
        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    else
        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


    CABasicAnimation *aAnimation;
    aAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

        CALayer *pLayer = placardView.layer;

        aAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
        aAnimation.duration = spinSpeed;
        aAnimation.cumulative = YES;
        aAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; 

        [pLayer addAnimation:aAnimation forKey:@"animatePlacardViewToSpin"];

        pLayer.opacity = spinOpacity;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you say what line it's crashing on.

Comment: it is actually pointing at line "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");" in my main.m

Comment: That's just the top frame that has source. The backtrace will show a bunch of OS functions instead, and I bet you'll find it's in the middle of CoreAnimation, trying to access the animation object.

Comment: I have the same problem with you. iOS 5-specific crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you're setting the `toValue` to an `NSValue`, but the key path is `transform.rotation`, which is isn't an `NSValue`. You should either be using `transform` as your keyPath, or you should be using `transform.rotation.z` (or whatever axis) as the keyPath and a simple `NSNumber` as your value.

Comment: I tried both. First one did not rotate, but without crash. The second one the same as before on iOS4.X working fine, with iOS5 crash by touching screen.